# Python Script (main) + Blender "face" animation

Tags: python, animation, 3d, artificial-intelligence, blender

SO I am infact doing something very similar to this user posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800292/python-ai-and-3d-animation

but it has no answers and I couldn't contact the user.

Basically I have a functioning python script that answers me with an action accordingly to my voice command. (Fetch emails, weather forecast, turn lights ON/OFF, etc), it has been made using the pyspeech library which is pretty darn good.

Now I want to give my programm a "face"! I thought about modelling the face with Blender (have some knowledge and would build up on it) and I know I could animate it, so the lips move and such.
So I want to know if it is at all possible to:

- Load the "face" that I made from blender from my main python script (so when my programm start the face would be there on the screen too)
- Run from the script the animations such that when for example when my programm says "You're welcome" I would run the animation that the lips move on the face to simulate it is speaking.

I know that blender has a good python integration (maybe correct is to say it is built on?) and that is why I thought it would be a good program to use.

Hope someone can help and tell me if that is at all possible and maybe show me some right way to go, my googling just showed me always python scripting with Blender which is not what I exactly need here... I think...

Cheers,

Flavio

Comment: by any chance is your project open-source ?

Comment: I can make the python script for voice commands available in my GIT repo, but I never made a lot of progress with the creation of the face animation if that is what you're asking

Comment: yes i believe that will be a starting point to play around

Comment: Hi, fditz, I am trying to create and animate an 3D face model. Is it possible in Blender? Could you point me to some resources? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937183/animation-of-a-3d-face-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, what you want is possible.
If all you want is to play pre-rendered animation videos based on decisions on your program, any GUI that allows you to embedd and play video in a widget will do for your application.

You could rool out your own GUI using Pygame (which has video support, but you will need one of the "minor" more or less "amateur" widget toolkits made for pygame to make up the remaining of your application, as pygame is pretty low level.

On a higher level, although I'had not embedded video, I think you could go with PyQT4 (googled a bit, not that many examples either, buthints that there are eamples in QT4 source) or GTK+ (the samething, it looks like there are more examples).

Another option would be to build your application to run inside the Blener Game Engine itself - It offers both a high level Toolkit, and ways to customize behaviors to user actions (even without coding).

The major drawback in doing this is: I don't know which are the options to distribute an application that needs Blender Game Engine nowadays - your users will need to install Blender (but it is likely Blender folks made an easy way to jhandle this).

On the upper hand: you get the most flexibility, it would even be possible to render some sequences in realtime (as opposed to pre-rendered videos) in your app.

One thing: Blender nowadays use Python 3.x - if the other libraries you need are Python 2, you willl need to make one different process for the GUI inside Blender, and exchange data with your application's backeend in Python 2 (for example using jsonrpc or xmlrpc - that is enoguh simple in Python).

Comment: Thanks so much! That was really helpfull! And complete for the matter of fact! :)